# LinearLayout Inside Fragment Always Leaves white space at the top

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments, layout, fragment

devs,

I am having issues with Fragments. The two LinearLayouts I have in my Home fragment always leave an unexplained white space at the top. This is causing problems as it is eating up space for the other UI elements that need to fit the fragment. See image. [linear layouts in fragment preceded by an unknown white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFbRn.jpg)

[edit] Included is the Layout File.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/black">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/teal_200">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: would be nice if you could provide your layout files

Comment: Can you provide the layout of the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make theme in `XML` file from yours to `AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

[image: Try that]

Or you can try to do it manual in `styles.xml` file :

from

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

In this specific case it was `android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize`
But mostly you will need the previous solution to fix that issue with the `ActionBar`. I keep that post updated, like all my posts.

Comment: There was this piece of code in the Layout with the BottomNavigation. On removing it everything went back to normal.
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: Okey. Glad that you fixed it! :) I add this to my answer, that it can help others. Happy Coding! :)